# How to convert ElasticSearch query to java

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elastic search 7.5 and how can I convert below query to java and how to get aggregation's result from the response.

```
curl -XGET --header 'Content-Type: application/json'  http://localhost:9200/product/_search?pretty -d '
{  
"size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "specs": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "specs"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "specList": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "specs.value",
            "size": 100
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: From your question, I'm assuming that you didn't check the Elastic documentation and tried something out. Please have a look at it and tell us whether it worked
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-aggs.html

Answer (score 0):

Building aggregation for your query using java Rest client API:

```
AggregationBuilder aggregationBuilder = AggregationBuilders
                .nested("specs","specs")
                .subAggregation(
                        AggregationBuilders.terms("specList").field("specs.value").size(100)
                );
```

Comment: How to set result size zero here?

Comment: you need to extract only aggregation results (Refer : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-search.html#java-rest-high-search-response-aggs)